# Switching IntelliJ Project from Java 8 to 11 gives compile error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, sdk

I try to switch from SDK 8 to SDK 11 in my IntelliJ Project as follow:
[image]

and I get the error:
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:157)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:76)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:405)
at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:481)
at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPackagingBuildTarget.doComputeRootDescriptors(AndroidPackagingBuildTarget.java:70)
at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidBuildTarget.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:83)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

My Project maybe special, because I have also a module which references the Android-SDK, which is needed.

[image]

The proposed solutions regarding the error did not help i found in other threads.
Anyone can help me?

Adding additional screenshots that shows the dependency added for jaxb
[image]

Comment: No This doesn't help. THis is already tried. I can see the dependency added but switching to 11 still shows the error.

Comment: Please show dependencies in the question. Currently no jaxb-like stuff there at all

Comment: I provided new screenshot. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well if it's building successfully we can probably take it that it's *not* being *run* by Maven. Whatever *is* running it is not placing jaxb on the classpath. You need to look into that and/or just make sure Maven *does* run it

Answer (score -1):

The javax.xml is removed in version 11 you have to use an addition dependency